# SQL Server - OPENJSON to parse JSON text

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following `JSON` text in a column defined as `nvarchar(max)`:

```
{"country":
    {"id":642,
    "name":"ROMANIA",
    "nameEn":"ROMANIA",
    "isoAlpha2":"RO",
    "isoAlpha3":"ROU",
    "currencyCode":"RON",
    "requireState":false,
    "addressType":1,
        "streetTypes":
        [
            {"name":"str.","nameEn":"str."},
            {"name":"","nameEn":""},
            {"name":"ale.","nameEn":"ale."},
            {"name":"int.","nameEn":"int."},
            {"name":"fdt.","nameEn":"fdt."},
            {"name":"pta.","nameEn":"pta."},
            {"name":"bld.","nameEn":"bld."},
            {"name":"drm.","nameEn":"drm."},
            {"name":"cal.","nameEn":"cal."},
            {"name":"sos.","nameEn":"sos."}
        ],
    "quarterTypes":[],
    "postCodeFormats":["","NNNNNN"]
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the value for ID, which is 642 and I have used the below statement but I was wondering if this is the right way to do it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 VALUE
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonBody, '$.country')
```

How can I extract only the value of id element without using `TOP 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql):

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonBody, '$.country.id')
```

The docs also have examples on how to access arrays of values.

Answer (score 0):

The more precise way to do it would be to actually indicate you want to return ID instead of making the assumption that it will always be the first value.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@, N'$.country')
WITH (id int '$.id')
```

Comment: Thanks @dfundako.